# Error in sql procedure

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

i got

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Flag_Account, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'while'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Flag_Account, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

when i try to run

```
    USE [hesabat2]
    GO

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    create  PROCEDURE [dbo].[Flag_Account]


    AS
begin
DECLARE @Acc_link int, @Result int,@inc int,@Result2 int
SET @inc = 0
set @Result =0
DECLARE A_Cursor CURSOR FOR
   Select account_id FROM ACCOUNTS
OPEN A_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM A_Cursor INTO @Acc_link

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS =0)
BEGIN

   set @Result= (select a.account_link from ACCOUNTS a where account_id= @Acc_link
   while(@Result = 0)
   begin
   set @Result = select a.account_link from ACCOUNTS a where account_id=@Result
   SET @inc= @inc+1
   end
    update ACCOUNTS set flag_color=@inc where account_id= @Acc_link



   FETCH NEXT FROM A_Cursor INTO  @Acc_link

   END

   CLOSE A_Cursor
   DEALLOCATE A_Cursor
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a ) on the line

```
set @Result= (select a.account_link from ACCOUNTS a where account_id= @Acc_link
```

Could be other things too, but try that first.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems.

This is missing a closing paren:

```
  set @Result= (select a.account_link from ACCOUNTS a where account_id= @Acc_link
```

And this is missing opening and closing parens:

```
  set @Result = select a.account_link from ACCOUNTS a where account_id=@Result
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct procedure is as follows:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Flag_Account]
AS 
begin 
DECLARE @Acc_link int, @Result int,@inc int,@Result2 int 
SET @inc = 0 
set @Result =0 
DECLARE A_Cursor CURSOR FOR Select account_id FROM ACCOUNTS 
OPEN A_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM A_Cursor INTO @Acc_link
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0 
BEGIN
set @Result= (select a.account_link from ACCOUNTS a where account_id= @Acc_link 
while  @Result = 0
   begin 
      set @Result = select a.account_link from ACCOUNTS a where account_id=@Result 
     SET @inc= @inc+1 end update ACCOUNTS set flag_color=@inc where account_id= @Acc_link
     FETCH NEXT FROM A_Cursor INTO @Acc_link
   END
end
CLOSE A_Cursor 
DEALLOCATE A_Cursor 
end
```